# open file by its full path

Tags: c++, file

I want to ask user the full path where the file exists and then keep the path in an array. So during the program I want to open the file that is exists in that place. 
but unfortunately I don't know how to open the file.
I tried the following code but it's not true.

```
    string address;
    cin>>address;
    ifstream file(address);
```

How do I open the file this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually that code works as it is – at least in the current version, C++11.

Before that, you need to convert the string to a C-style string:

```
ifstream file(address.c_str());
```

Although you should beware of spaces in the file’s path as CapelliC mentioned in his (now-deleted) answer; in order to ensure that the user can enter paths with spaces (such as “`~/some file.txt`”), use `std::getline` instead of the stream operator:

```
getline(cin, address);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open (adresse.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

possibily a problem could be the presence of space in `address`.

Try using getline(cin, address) instead (thanks to Konrad to spot the problem, my C++ it's a bit rusty...)

Comment: You cannot use `std::cin::getline` on a `std::string`.

Comment: Yes, I'll delete it -- again !